# VB datagrid binding source filter

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have programmed my datagridview connection rather using the built in wizard function. Only problem I'm having now is I cant seem to SQL filter search the binding source as i type. What I mean by this, is I want to filter the data of the 'SkuNo' column of my database as shown on the datagrid as I type into a text box. This is very easy and works well with a wizard but I'm struggling doing it through the code. This is my code:

```
 Private Sub txtSearchOnSku_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearchOnSku.TextChanged
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource()

    DataGridView1.DataSource = source1

    source1.Filter = "skuNo LIKE'" & txtSearchOnSku.Text & "*'"
End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: What happens? What do you get? Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: The datagrid goes blank. If i have (for example) a data item that begins with the letter 'c', i type 'c' into the textbox and that single result should appear in the datagrid as its being typed, but it dosent it just displays as empty.

Comment: The code you posted creates a `BindingSource`, but doesn't populate it, so `DataGridView1.DataSource = source1` connects your datagrid to an empty list.

Comment: Should the * in the query be a % ?

Comment: @David has a good point - also why do you create a BindingSource every time inside TextChanged?

Comment: Tim, i thought the same on the wildcard '%' but that appears not to be the case in VB. And Neoslick, that was just some rough code i was using to try and get it working. All sorted now though. Ty all.

Comment: Neoslick? Hmm... I guess you did not play Starcraft... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorted it guys

Heres the code:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM duragadget"
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(duraGadgetDB)
Dim dataadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)
Dim ds As New DataSet()
Dim dsView As New DataView
Dim bs As New BindingSource()
connection.Open()
dataadapter.Fill(ds, "dura")
connection.Close()
dsView = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
bs.DataSource = dsView
bs.Filter = "skuNo LIKE'" & txtSearchOnSku.Text & "*'"
DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
```

Comment: Hope you are not doing it every time on TextChanged. Also don't forget to accept your answer as soon as you can (I know there is a delay before you can do it).